# Ajax and ActiveXObject

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, msxml

why when I run this code on local server, `req.send(sData)` doesn't work?
It runs `alert1` but doesn't run `alert2`;

```
function initialize() {
    var req;
    try {
        req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (oc) {
            req = null;
        }
    }
    if (!req && typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined") {
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return req;
}

function getData(sUrl, sData) {
    var req = initialize();
    req.open("POST", sUrl, false);
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    alert("1");
    req.send(sData);
    alert("2");
    return req.responseText;
}
```

`sUrl and sData` are the same as the original website sends.

Comment: what is your sdata value?

Comment: sData = data=d_autogen1[]d_autogen1[]d_autogen2[]d_autogen2[]From[MHD]To[ABD]Date[2014___S_L_A_S_H___03___S_L_A_S_H___31]Counter[1]TypeSort[Price]&pageaction=getdata&SystemID=2aad5e28-3dd2-4674-8078-a40a143eaf88&LanguageID=b3642705-78ba-4f5a-be67-e18ad8837255&Stats=Search

Comment: I should say that there is a website with this codes and it shows results of flight informations. I want to send a custom request to it's ajax url and get results.